# Run non-markup Angular Code

Tags: angularjs

I am writing some Angular code which polls a server and shows a notification if the server says to.

I would like this to be a stand-alone js file which can be included into any site (assuming the site already loads Angular). The issue I am having it getting the code to run without any markup in the HTML.

If I make it the init function of a controller and use that controller in the page it works well. But that requires I add markup to the HTML.

How can I have the code run without markup in the HTML? (And as close as possible to the *Angular* way).

Comment: How, and where, is the notification supposed to be displayed if the user doesn't add any HTML anywhere?

Comment: A popup modal that is dynamically added to the body.

Comment: Provide a service, and tell the developer to call it from a run() method: `myModule.run(function(pollingService) { pollingService.startPolling(); })`. Or just add the run() on your own module, and just tell the user to depend on your module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a service, and tell the developer to call it from a `run()` function:

```
myModule.run(function(pollingService) { 
    pollingService.startPolling(); 
}).
```

Or, if you don't even want to force the developer to add this function, and always start polling when the app starts up, just add the `run()` on your own module, and tell the developer to depend on your module.